# How to choose suitable Autoencoder (LSTM) architecture?

Tags: time-series, lstm, autoencoders, keras

I am new to Autoencoders and I am a bit confused on which model to try for my situation and what is the difference between all the different models I have seen in tutorials.

So, I have a set of time-series of a certain length `w`, so my input dataset `X` has a shape `(5000,50,1)`, where 5000 is the amount of small time-series and `w=50`.

I have seen the following options:

1. LSTM -> Dense -> Linear Activation. For me it seems that the decoding layer is missing here. Or this would still work?
2. LSTM(64) -> RepeatVector(`w`) -> LSTM(`w`). This one gives me the error, because it's output seems to be of shape (`None, w, w`), while I would actually expect (`None, w, 1`), corresponding to the original input. How to fix this problem? Or it is actually supposed to be like that and I just don't understand something about Autoencoders? Here is the code that I used:

`def create_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(w,1)))
        model.add(RepeatVector(w))
        model.add(LSTM(w, return_sequences=True))
        return model`

3. Same architecture but divided into separate Encoder and Decoder model. I haven't tried this because I would prefer just one model. Or is this option also worth trying?

Thanks.